# PHPUnit Test Explorer Plugin for VScode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpunit

I'm new to VScode coming from PHPStorm only cause Github Copilot chat is better than PHPStorm. I'm having trouble setting up PHPUnit Test Explorer for VSCode. I always get this annoying error:

❌ Could not open input file: vendor/bin/phpunit

It works perfectly fine in PHPStorm and in VScode in the terminal (bash) when I run the command "./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testSomeTestFunction". I'm trying to run my tests like in PHPStorm it's just the way I'm used to it.

My setup is Laravel Homestead/vagrant. I have PHP installed in my Windows 10 machine in: C:\php82

and my current project has a "server" directory where Laravel application is in.

This is my current VScode settings.json file:

```
{
    "editor.inlineSuggest.suppressSuggestions": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "phpunit.php": "C:\\php82\\php.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.lineHeight": 1.2,
    "[php]": {},
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\php82\\php.exe",
    "phpunit.clearOutputOnRun": true,
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1",
    "phpunit.paths": {
        "c:/Users/User/code/myproject/server": "./vendor/bin"
    }
}
```

My projects are in the typical "code" directory. If you need more info, definitely let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
```

> I made some changes in json below try this

```
{
    "editor.inlineSuggest.suppressSuggestions": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "phpunit.php": "C:\\php82\\php.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.lineHeight": 1.2,
    "[php]": {},
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\php82\\php.exe",
    "phpunit.clearOutputOnRun": true,
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1",
    "phpunit.paths": {
        "c:/Users/User/code/myproject/server": "./vendor/bin"
    },
    "phpunit.customOptions": {
        "testSuffix": ".php",
        "bootstrap": "c:/Users/User/code/myproject/server/bootstrap/app.php",
        "colors": "never"
    }
}
```